# Getting user location using wikitude SDK for Android

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, wikitude

I'm currently using wikitude sdk 4.0 for android and trying out the the sample of Multiple POIs in my app.
https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-sdk-samples/tree/master/3_PointOfInterest_3_MultiplePois

I got it instantiated but stuck with user location.

I don't understand how the user's location is pulled by this Javascript 
https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-sdk-samples/blob/master/3_PointOfInterest_3_MultiplePois/js/multiplepois.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "AR.context.onLocationChanged = World.locationChanged;" in JS does the magic.

After this line is executed the 'World.locationChanged' (or any other given) function is fired on every Android/iOS native call of the architectView's setLocation is executed.

Check out the LocationProvider-implementation in the Sample Application for a very basic approach.
For state-of-the-art location fetching I recommend you to have a look at [Google's Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

Kind regards.